# NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \* when moving home directories to another location

Tags: samba, acl, access-control

I have a server and just finished building my raids. One of the partitions is supposed to house my home folders which I then want to share with my windows computers through samba. Before I begin migration of all my data I created a user to test if I can move my home folders from `/home/<user>` over to the path `/mnt/volume1/homes/<user>`. The move worked without problems through `usermod -m -d /mnt/volume1/homes user`, just the access to the share stops working after the move.

I logged in to smbclient with the user and when I enter `ls` or `dir` all I get is `NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED LISTING /*`. I made sure the user has full control over the folder with `setfacl -R -m u:<user>:rwx /mnt/volume1/homes/<user>` in addition to being owner, for the user himself as well as the group. When I login to the smbclient accessing the original home folder in `/home/<user>` everything works like a charm.

I also tried [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50437580/3176132) but that didn't work either. I also found a post that suggested to execute `sudo chcon -R -t samba_share_t /mnt/volume1/homes/<user>` but that did not work.

My question: How do I have to create or move the homes shares to the position `/mnt/volume1/homes` and configure Samba so I can access them.

Answer (score 1):

by accident I discovered the solution to my issue. Setting the rights with setfacl was the right solution just the level I applied these rights to was not right. I had them assigned to only the users folder `/mnt/volume1/homes/<user>`. The right level was to set these rights the level `/mnt/volume1/`. Once I set these rights on that level, everything worked like a charm.